What IP adress do I point my domain to?
Im currently trying to host my website after buying a domain and adding it to cloudflare. But I dont get which IP Adress I need to enter there, as it cant be my local IP adress but I also dk if I am supposed to use my routers IP. IK this is probably a dumb question but thank you for the help!

You set the DNS entry to the IP address of the server hosting the website. The IP address must NOT be an intranet IP address.

@Ramhound unless it is supposed to be an intranet site that is only locally available.

@LPChip - If it’s a intranet website then they don’t need Cloudflare.

@Ramhound yeah, that's true, but the word must suggests that it cannot be done, and this is technically not true.

@LPChip - I didn’t think it was relevant for a website using Cloudflare services

@Ramhound in the rare occasion where someone doesn't have a DNS server but has the domain and a pc is functioning as a webserver, one could potentially use this.

I know a lot about this topic as I administrate my own web app, and if you’re a beginner it’s not a stupid question at all!- however it is very easy to find this info online.
When you're hosting a website and have already purchased a domain and added it to Cloudflare, the IP address you need to enter is very important. This IP address must be the public IP address of the server where your website is hosted, not your local IP address.
Your local IP address is assigned to your devices within your home or business network and often look something like 192.168.x.x or 10.0.x.x. Your router IP address is a similar concept too, so these addresses are only local and not routable over the internet and cannot be used for your website's DNS settings, if this wasn’t obvious.
You need to use your public IP address. I assume you know how to see what your public IP is, but if you don’t, just search up “what is my IP address” and you’ll get a million results of websites to try. And this is the address seen by the rest of the internet when you connect to websites and services. Sometimes your router panel might include your current public IP, but I’d just go with a website because sometimes the router panel isn’t very clear on what variation of IP it mean, especially if you don’t know what you’re doing.
If you are hosting the website from your home computer, ensure that your router forwards HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic to the local IP address of your computer. This process is known as port forwarding. On the other hand, if you are using a web hosting service, the service provider will give you an IP address (or a hostname) where your site is hosted- so in the his case use this.
Once you have the correct IP address, log in to your Cloudflare account and select the domain you’ve added. Navigate to the DNS settings section. Here, you will need to add an "A" record where the "Name" field is your domain name (or "@" for the root domain), and the "IPv4 address" field is the public IP address if you are hosting the site from home, or if you are using the IP address provided by your hosting service.
If your public IP address is dynamic, meaning it changes often, you will need a dynamic DNS service to keep your domain pointed to the correct IP. Cloudflare offers this service as well, which can help you keep your DNS records updated automatically.
Ensuring your server is properly secured is also critical, as exposing it directly to the internet can make it a target for attacks, as I’ve learnt the hard way!!
